# How to use recursion with elements in the list?

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, scheme, compare

I'm trying to use recursion in the list and I need to go through all elements. Here is my code:

```
(define compare
  (lambda (ls pred?)
    (if (null? list)
        #f
        (pred? (list-ref ls (- (length ls) 2)) (list-ref ls (- (length ls) 1))))))
```

But it works only with last two elements. Result should be like this:

```
(compare '(1 2 3 4 5) <) -> #t
(compare '(1 2 8 4 5) <) -> #f
```

Do you have any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *not* using recursion anywhere in the code. In fact, it has errors and I don't think you tested it thoroughly. For example:

- The `if` condition should be `(null? ls)`
- Using `list-ref` is not the way to go when traversing a list in Scheme, for that in general you want to use recursion, `car`, `cdr`, etc.
- Again, where is the recursive call? `compare` should be called at some point!

I believe this is what you intended, it's not recursive but it's the simplest way to implement the procedure:

```
(define (compare ls pred?)
  (apply pred? ls))
```

Because this looks like homework I can only give you some hints for solving the problem from scratch, without using `apply`. Fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (compare ls pred?)
  (if <???>                    ; special case: if the list is empty
      <???>                    ; then return true
      (let loop ((prev <???>)  ; general case, take 1st element
                 (ls   <???>)) ; and take the rest of the list
        (cond (<???>           ; again: if the list is empty
               <???>)          ; then return true
              (<???>           ; if pred? is false for `prev` and current element
               <???>)          ; then return false
              (else            ; otherwise advance the recursion
               (loop <???> <???>)))))) ; pass the new `prev` and the rest of the list
```

Notice that I used a named `let` for implementing the recursion, so `loop` is the recursive procedure here: you can see that `loop` is being called inside `loop`. Alternatively you could've defined a helper procedure. I had to do this for taking into account the special case where the list is initially empty.

The recursion works like this for the general case: two parameters are required, `prev` stores the previous element in the list and `ls` the rest of the list. at each point in the traversal we check to see if the predicates is false for the previous and the current element - if that is the case, then we return false. If not, we continue the recursion with a new `prev` (the current element) and the rest of the list. We keep going like this until the list is empty and only then we return true.

Comment: I know about apply but I can't use it. It is the problem. :(

Comment: I'm a little bit silly. What should be here:  (<???>           ; if pred? is false for `prev` and current element. And here: (loop <???> <???>)))))) ; pass the new `prev` and the rest of the list. In ??-> (loop (car list) (cdr list))) or something else

Comment: @Ats: the second part is correct. For the first part: this is the core of the procedure, think about it: what would make the whole procedure return false? how about this: that the previous element and the current element, when compared with `pred?`, evaluate to false.

Comment: I have tried it all the day, but nothing is working. I tried: (pre? (car lis) prev), (pre? prev (car lis)). I don't know what I should write there.

Comment: @Ats you almost got it ... ok, I'll help you with the final detail - we return false _if `pred?` is false_. This is what I meant: `(not (pred? prev (car ls)))`. I hope this solves your problem, please don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful for you.